# How to pass touch control to parent view ,while still keep touch events of some part of child views?

Tags: android, html, touch, android-webview, multi-touch

parent and childs have their default touch events
I want to pass touch event to parent, while touch for several part of child
need to work the touch event of child,I mean the standard touch events of child(webview) should be called I load in webView youtube soundCloud and when the part of soundCloud or youtube is touched it's default events should be called (start/stop/...)
I pass touch events to parent by

```
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
return true;}
```

while I still need to have control of some parts of child view touch events

Comment: if you return true the you are intercepting the event, but you say you want to pass it to the child views?